# Struts2 jQuery UI dynamic Menu from Action List

Tags: java, jquery-ui, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

How can I generate dynamic menu & menu items from a list generated at Action?
I tried this approach but it is generating only main menu but not sub-menus.

**Action class:**

```
private List<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
public String execute(){
    menuList.add("Menu1");
    menuList.add("Menu2");
    menuList.add("Menu3");
    menuList.add("Menu4");
    return "success";
}
public List<String> getMenuList() {
    return menuList;
}
public void setMenuList(List<String> menuList) {
    this.menuList = menuList;
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<sj:menu cssStyle="width:50%" list="menuList" />
```

What can i do to get Menu with menu items?

**Example classes structure:**

```
public class Menu {
    private String id;
    private List<MenuItem> menuItems;

    public Menu(String id, List<MenuItem> menuItems){
        this.id = id;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<MenuItem> getMenuItems() {
        return menuItems;
    }
    public void setMenuItems(List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }   
}



public class MenuItem {
    private String title;
    private String href;
    private Menu menu;  // submenu

    public MenuItem(String title, String href, Menu menu){
        this.title = title;
        this.href = href;
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }
    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }
    public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }   
}
```

How to configure this in JSP page with `sj:menu` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<sj:menu>` tag generates a menu from list values, to create submenu you should use `<sj:menuItem>` in the body of `<sj:menu>` tag.

Also in the body of `<sj:menuItem>` you can use `<sj:menu>` tag.

The detailed explanation and example you can find [here](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/MenuTag).

Comment: Thanks Roman for your reply, How can I use those struts-jquery tags to create dynamic menu, menuitems with action filled property list. Is it possible to use them with iterator tag, or if I want to use list property value of sj:menu what should be the structure of List that contains menu, menuitems & menuitems, menu data.

Comment: You can use iterator tag for menus or menu items, the list is a simple structure that contains menu items, that can't contain submenus.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the iterator tag of struts2 [(link)](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html)

It takes a java.util.Collection as an input an iterate over its values.